# Serving Static HTML in Flask while performing some DB operations

Tags: python, nginx, flask, static, gunicorn

I have an end point in my flask application where I want to perform some logging in the DB and then serve a static HTML file in the response. The end point looks like this:

```
@app.route("/man/<os>/<section>/<name>")
```

I have thousands of different HTML files, and it depends on the URL, which one of them needs to be returned. I have configured Nginx to serve all the static files. But, I am handling these URLs in Flask, doing the logging in the DB, and streaming the HTML file through the requests module (see below)

```
    host = request.host
    path = 'man_pages/' + os + '/html' + section + '/' + name + '.html'
    url = 'http://' + host + url_for('static', filename=path) #TODO don't hardcode the scheme
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type=req.headers['content-type'])
```

This is resulting in two requests to Nginx and I don't believe this is the most efficient method of doing this. Is there any way to do the logging in the DB in the flask application and then use Nginx to serve the static HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make it with only one request.

Other web servers have the `X-Sendfile` header and `Flask` has built-in support for it.

Nginx does not support this header, it has the similar [X-Accel-Redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/). Unfortunately, [Flask does not support it](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/72)

You must configure an `nginx` route to support it and make `Flask` return the `X-Accel-Redirect` header.

Take a look at the [xsendfile](http://pythonhosted.org/xsendfile/howto.html#using-nginx-as-front-end-server), I think it can be useful to you.

I'm not giving you a complete solution, because I think you just need a hint and some pointers about the `X-Accel-Redirect` header.

Some other useful resources:

https://gist.github.com/jessejlt/1306827

http://www.mli.gmu.edu/toz/wordpress/2014/07/31/serving-files-with-flask-behind-nginx-gunicorn/